# Is it necessary to put the login checkcode into redis?

Tags: web, redis

Is it high performance to put checkcode into redis or session?If you put redis in, should the key be sessionID?

Comment: can you please elaborate? what do you mean by "verification code" ?

Comment: thx，I just mean that how to use checkcode.